# Parallel texts with reledpar in columns

Tags: reledmac, paracol, reledpar, parallel-texts

I am trying to typeset three texts in parallel columns like this:
1. The left column has an ancient text and its critical apparatus.
2. The middle column has an ancient translation of this text and its critical apparatus.
3. The right column has my translation into English. Since this last column is only for reference, it has no need for an apparatus or anything else fancy.

I know reledpar cannot handle three parallel texts, but is it possible to hack it and typeset two parallel texts with reledpar on 2/3 of the paper and on the remaining third put a column that has a modern translation, without an apparatus? This is what I've come up with some far. TeX complains about `! You can't use macro parameter character #' in internal vertical mode`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A},noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{paracol}
\sethangingsymbol{[\,}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.3\textwidth}  
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.3\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\stanza
Some text &
in Greek \&
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\stanza
Some text &
in Latin\&
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\switchcolumn
\begin{verse}[0.30\linewidth]
\begin{altverse}
My translation \\
goes here
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish `reledmac`/`reledpar` allowed for more than two columns, too, but it doesn't. One thought I've had for a similar project is to create two documents and then interweave them into a master document using `pdfpages`. However, I was anticipating four columns, which means text balancing would be easier. With three columns as you describe them, I don't see any way to avoid a lot of whitespace (unless the apparatus are quite large). In turn, that means page synchronization for the interweaving method probably would require much manual intervention....

Comment: unfortunately, I have no idea without rewriting all reledpar code (one / two/three  month of work?)